# Python: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level: Textual to Numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im currently trying to manipulate the data to change the textual values to Numberic and am recieving the below error with my code. Please help. I am using juypter notebook and started off by importing pandas as pd
and imported the data set as dF

```
Null = dF.isnull() .any()

dF = dF.drop([["customerID", "gender", "SeniorCitizen", "Partner", "Dependents", "tenure", "PhoneService", "MultipleLines", "InternetService", "OnlineSecurity", "OnlineBackup", "DeviceProtection", "TechSupport", "StreamingTV", "StreamingMovies", "Contract", "PaperlessBilling", "PaymentMethod", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges", "Churn"]], axis=1)

for column in range(len(list(dF.columns.values))):
    for index, row in dF.iterrows():
         if "No" in row[column] or "Female" in row[column]:
            dF.iloc[index, column] = 0
    
        elif "Yes" in row[column] or "Male" in row[column]:
            dF.iloc[index, column] = 1
```

dF.to_excel('Cleaned.xlsx', index=False)

**ERROR IM RECIEVING BELOW**

```
File "<tokenize>", line 10
   elif "Yes" in row[column] or "Male" in row[column]:
   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Answer (score -1):

See the docs for .drop(). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html There are a couple things you are missing:

```
1. you're not actually dropping the rows (see inplace=True)
2. for more than one column it needs to be passed as list
3. you need to tell it the axis; defaults to index and you want columns
```

try to adapt this to what you want (note double brackets)

```
df.drop([['col1', 'col2', ...]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

instead of using inplace you could do this:

```
df = df.drop([['col1', 'col2', ...]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Do dF.columns on your data frame and paste what you have please. Before trying to drop.  And paste the exact code of what you are using to drop the columns. Thx.

Comment: I used the option instead of using inplace and this made the error much smaller now I am receiving an IndentationError on the elif.  "File "<tokensize>", line 10 Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level